# Getting a list of all the other objects pointing to an object

Tags: java, object

Given a Java Object, how can I get a list of Objects that referring to it? Is this possible within the java language?

Comment: Please elaborate your question more with some example it will be helpful in replying to your question.

Comment: I have this 2d game in which each tile is an object and have other objects (players/vegatation) pointing at it. I want a way to get these  other objects pointing at the tile

Comment: So,Players and vegatation is the reference variables as far as I am getting it.Reference variables always point towards the object residing in the heap.there may be number of reference variables which can point to a single object.There is no way you can get at object side that what is the list of reference variables which are pointing to this object.

Answer (score 0):

The brute-force way would be to iterate through the players/vegatations and looking for the reference or you need to put these dependencies in a "central" management object like a map.

Besides that Java does not provide any built-in features to get the objects referencing to an object.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in Java. This is because the referring object holds a reference to the pointed-to object. The pointed-to object does not keep track of what has a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

There are no API methods to do this. But of course you can do manually by creating a tile class and giving all the referencing objects as fields or you can you can do this using a control object like map.